# Logstash grok filter fails to match for some messages

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to parse my application's logs with logstash (version 1.4.2) and grok, but for some reason I don't understand, grok fails to parse some of the lines that should match the specified filter. I've searched Google and Stackoverflow, but most of the problems other people had seemed to be related to multiline log messages (which isn't the case for me), and I couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

My filter looks like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGBASE} -(?<script>\w*)-: Adding item with ID %{WORD:item_id} to database."}
    add_tag => ["insert_item"]
  }
}
```

Here's the message field of a line that is parsed correctly:

```
May 11 16:47:55 myhost rqworker: -script-: Adding item with ID 982663745238221172_227691295 to database.
```

And here's the message field of a line that isn't:

```
May 11 16:47:55 myhost rqworker: -script-: Adding item with ID 982663772746479443_1639853260 to database.
```

The only thing that differs between these messages is the item's ID, and [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) parses them both correctly.

I've checked the logstash log file, but didn't see any relevant error messages.

I'm just starting out with logstash and have no idea what is happening here; any help would be much appreciated!